# Bound mismatch for java generics for a spring app

Tags: java, spring, generics

I am trying to create a REST api using Spring MVC. Instead of writing CRUD methods for each of the controller, I created an abstract class that would take care of the typical REST CRUD scenarios. So I created these following classes

```
public interface DomainObject<ID extends Serializable> {}

public class Apps implements DomainObject<String>{}

public interface AppsRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Apps, String> {}

public abstract class AbstractController<T extends PagingAndSortingRepository<DomainObject<Serializable>, Serializable>> {}
```

With the above class/interface definitions, how do I declare a class that extends the AbstractController?

I tried declaring AppsController using

```
public class AppsController extends AbstractController<AppsRepository>{}
```

without any luck. Eclipse is showing the following error

```
Bound mismatch: The type AppsRepository is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends PagingAndSortingRepository<DomainObject<Serializable>,Serializable>> of the type AbstractController<T>
```

I am totally stuck. I have tried different approches for a while without any luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A Controller should never *be* a Repository, instead it should *have* one.

Comment: You are right. I changed my code to follow Ian's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same way as `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>`, `PagingAndSortingRepository<Apps, String>` (and therefore `AppsRepository`) is not a subtype of `PagingAndSortingRepository<DomainObject<Serializable>, Serializable>`

You could use wildcards, as it is an extension of `PagingAndSortingRepository<? extends DomainObject<? extends Serializable>,? extends Serializable>>` but if you do that then you're very limited in what you can do in the `AbstractController`, for example you can't have any methods that take parameters of the domain object's ID type because you don't know what that type is in the general case.

You need to declare the relevant type variables in `AbstractController`:

```
public abstract class AbstractController<IDT extends Serializable, KT extends Serializable,
    Dom extends DomainObject<IDT>, T extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Dom, KT>> {

  private T repository;

  public AbstractController(T repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
  }

  public Dom get(IDT objectId) {
    return repository.get(objectId);
  }
}
```

and make `AppsController` extend `AbstractController<String, String, Apps, AppsRepository>`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed my code to follow the guideline you provided. Could you please elaborate on your thinking process as to how you figured it out?